# Icons with gradient colors

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons, expo

Is there any way I can add gradient colors to Icons in react-native / expo?

I want to make icons like those :
[image]

Comment: If they are svg icons, you can directly edit the file and add a 'gradient' property.

Comment: @Papooch Thank you this seems to be good solution, but is there any way I can use vector-icons and add to them gradient color?

Comment: SVG is a vector format, you can directly edit it in a text editor to add the gradient tag, or use a vector graphics program like Inkscape or Adobe Ilustrator. If you are asking if there is a way to add the gradient _programatically_, I don't think there is a simple way, you would have to play with overlays and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Tried this variant using MaskedView and LinearGradient packages https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/198#issuecomment-590821900. I use this snippet with Icon from native-base and this solution works perfectly for me.

```js
    import React from 'react'
    import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
    import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient'
    import MaskedView from '@react-native-community/masked-view'

    const size = 40

    export function PowerOff({ ...rest }) {
    return (
    <View style={{ width: size }} {...rest}>
      <MaskedView
        style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', height: size }}
        maskElement={
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <Icon
              name="power"
              size={size}
              color="white"
              style={styles.shadow}
            />
          </View>
        }>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['#F7C650', 'rgba(247, 198, 80, 0.71)']}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </MaskedView>
    </View>
      )
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    shadow: {
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 1,
        },
      },
    })
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

const GradientIcon = (props) => {
  return (
    <MaskedView maskElement={<MaterialCommunityIcons {...props} />}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={props.colors}
        start={props.start}
        end={props.end}
        locations={props.locations}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons
          {...props}
          style={{
            opacity: 0,
          }}
        />
      </LinearGradient>
    </MaskedView>
  );
};

export default GradientIcon;
```